# What options do I have to make an static import not being dependent on a physical file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, qwik

I'm using [Qwik](https://qwik.builder.io) and I can't use dynamic import. Thus I have this line of code:

```
import { OverridenLayout } from 'BlogOverride'
```

This means that in my `tsconfig.json` file, I need to configure a barrel:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "BlogOverride": [
                "src/Modules/Blog/Exports"
            ],
```

This means that the `src/Modules/Blog/Exports` file should be present, and it should export a named component called `OverridenLayout`.

This makes our life very difficult, because even if we don't want to override a layout, we need to include that file, and write some boilerplate code in it.

What can I do to make this dynamic layout loading possible, without boilerplate code?

Comment: How do you use the conditional export in your code? Also, while I know nothing about qwik, I don't see why you would be prevented from using dynamic imports which are available natively in evergreen browsers.